# Symfony2 / Doctrine : OneToMany/ManyToOne between 2 bundles

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have 2 bundles : a core one (C) and an optional one (O).

I create an entity in O with a OneToMany property referring an entity in C.

I want to inject the related ManyToOne in the entity in C (I can't write it in C because 0 is optional)

I saw the resolve_target_entities orm capabilities but I doesn't look good for my usecase, it looks to be only if you want to switch between bundles.

Have you an idea how to do that?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT1:**

You can simply extend the `SomeCoreEntity` in your `O` Bundle and add what you need:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\OptionalBundle\Entity;
use Vendor\CoreBundle\Entity\SomeCoreEntity as BaseEntity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

Class NewEntity extends BaseEntity
{

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vendor\OptionalBundle\Entity\NewEntity" mappedBy="coreEntity")
 */
private $optionalEntities;

public function __construct() {
    $this->optionalEntities = ArrayCollection();
}

}
```

**Original Answer:**

Did you try writing it like this in `O` Bundle:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\OptionalBundle\Entity

Class SomeOptionalEntity
{

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Vendor\CoreBundle\Entity\SomeCoreEntity")
 */
private $coreEntity;

}
```

Comment: yes, this part is correctly generated, but I want a bidirectioanl association. I add an inversedBy parameter which didn't provide errors while building even if the parameter and annotation in C didn't exists.

Comment: I think I can do using PHP mapping : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/php-mapping.html but I don't know the good place to put the code.

Comment: thank you for your example but it doesn't do exactly what I need : I want to have my entity in my core bundle as if i added the manytoone in it.

Comment: The entity will stay in the core. You can extend it in the optional bundle to modify it to your desire. That's the only way I can personally think of to do that and still keep Core Bundle totally unaware about your optional bundles.